# Package to identify dimensions of non-standard shape (image processing)

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to calculate the motion of dust particles, and I can't seem to find a package that can identify the dimensions of a non-standard shape (i.e. approximately the radius if we assume the dust particle to be circular.

Say if I had the following image, and feed the package the location of the 'centre' of one of these particles, it would return some dimensions (shape, major-axis radius etc).

![dust] (**https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/47071656_339293956870649_3030152264015675392_n.png?_nc_cat=106&_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.xx&oh=b72ca130a01659d870f085ae8a5a0e87&oe=5CB1C1FF**

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it
Please have a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: **OpenCV** is your friend. Python or C++. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html